# Python: object with a list of objects - create methods based on properties of list members

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, object, attributes

I have a class which contains a list like so:

```
class Zoo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._animals = []
```

I populate the list of animals with animal objects that have various properties:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, speed, height, length):
        self._speed = speed
        self._height = height
        self._length = length
```

You can imagine subclasses of Animal that have other properties. I want to be able to write methods that perform the same calculation but on different attributes of the Animal. For example, an average. I could write the following in Zoo:

```
def get_average(self, propertyname):
    return sum(getattr(x, propertyname) for x in self.animals) / len(self.animals)
```

That string lookup not only messes with my ability to document nicely, but using `getattr` seems odd (and maybe I'm just nervous passing strings around?). If this is good standard practice, that's fine. Creating `get_average_speed()`, `get_average_height()`, and `get_average_length()` methods, especially as I add more properties, seems unwise, too.

I realize I am trying to encapsulate a one-liner in this example, but is there a better way to go about creating methods like this based on properties of the objects in the Zoo's list? I've looked a little bit at factory functions, so when I understand them better, I think I could write something like this:

```
all_properties = ['speed', 'height', 'length']
for p in all_properties:
    Zoo.make_average_function(p)
```

And then any instance of Zoo will have methods called `get_average_speed()`, `get_average_height()`, and `get_average_length()`, ideally with nice docstrings. Taking it one step further, I'd really like the Animal objects themselves to tell my Zoo what properties can be turned into `get_average()` methods. Going to the very end, let's say I subclass Animal and would like it to indicate it creates a new average method: *(the following is pseudo-code, I don't know if decorators can be used like this)*

```
class Tiger(Animal):
    def __init__(self, tail_length):
        self._tail_length = tail_length

    @Zoo.make_average_function
    @property
    def tail_length(self):
        return self._tail_length
```

Then, upon adding a Tiger to a Zoo, my method that adds animals to Zoo object would know to create a `get_average_tail_length()` method for that instance of the Zoo. Instead of having to keep a list of what average methods I need to make, the Animal-type objects indicate what things can be averaged.

Is there a nice way to get this sort of method generation? Or is there another approach besides `getattr()` to say "do some computation/work on an a particular property of every member in this list"?

Comment: seems pretty complex, but...  thing is, as you point out not all animals have same attributes/properties.  so the zoo cant just dig in and look at frog tail lenghts to average.  as i said, pretty complex, but i’d have animals register their tail length, horn size, etc to a centralized zoo-level dict.  attribute name as key, themselves in a list. then the zoo can figure what to do from that registry.

Comment: I agree your solution is simpler and safer! I had reached the point of curiosity about how functions truly became methods for objects, and Mad Lee's answer below helped sate me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import functools
class Zoo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._animals = []

    @classmethod
    def make_average_function(cls, func):
        setattr(cls, "get_average_{}".format(func.__name__), functools.partialmethod(cls.get_average, propertyname=func.__name__))
        return func

    def get_average(self, propertyname):
        return sum(getattr(x, propertyname) for x in self._animals) / len(self._animals)


class Animal:
    def __init__(self, speed, height, length):
        self._speed = speed
        self._height = height
        self._length = length


class Tiger(Animal):
    def __init__(self, tail_length):
        self._tail_length = tail_length

    @property
    @Zoo.make_average_function
    def tail_length(self):
        return self._tail_length


my_zoo = Zoo()
my_zoo._animals.append(Tiger(10))
my_zoo._animals.append(Tiger(1))
my_zoo._animals.append(Tiger(13))
print(my_zoo.get_average_tail_length())
```

Note: If there are different zoos have different types of animals, it will lead to confusion.

Example

```
class Bird(Animal):
    def __init__(self, speed):
        self._speed = speed

    @property
    @Zoo.make_average_function
    def speed(self):
        return self._speed

my_zoo2 = Zoo()
my_zoo2._animals.append(Bird(13))
print(my_zoo2.get_average_speed())   # ok
print(my_zoo.get_average_speed()) # wrong
print(my_zoo2.get_average_tail_length()) # wrong
```